# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sinh(\sqrt{s})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I was just wondering if it is possible to determine the Inverse Laplace Transforms of the function

$$F(s) = \frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sinh(\sqrt{s} )}$$

by utilising the Residue theorem. I am fine in finding the residues at $s=n^2 \pi^2$, however, I am having trouble finding the residue at $s=0$.

I think the question itself might be incorrect and is meant to be, instead

$$F(s) = \frac{\sqrt s}{s \sinh(\sqrt{s} )}$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $s=0$ is a removable discontinuity for $\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sinh\sqrt{s}}$ and a simple pole with residue $1$ for $\frac{\sqrt{s}}{s\sinh\sqrt{s}}$.

Comment: Of course, I completely forgot about the fact that it is removable, and so the true singularities will only be at $s=n^2 \pi^2$. Thanks for the help

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{s}}{s \sinh \left(\sqrt{s}\right)}\right](t)=\frac{\vartheta _2\left(0,e^{-1/t}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }
   \sqrt{t}}$ where $ \vartheta _2$ is EllipticTheta function.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sinh \left(\sqrt{s}\right)}\right](t)=-2 \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } (-1)^j e^{-j^2 \pi ^2 t} j^2 \pi ^2$.  I doubt there's a closed form for the sum.